# How to modify CDDB tags easily on ripping under linux?

Tags: tags, music-management

my situation: I have a linux box and I want to rip and encode some CDs. The CDs contain music for dancing, so the exact speed is sometimes needed (Bars per minute).

For now I am using ripit with CDDB querys. Often it finds correct values for the track names. Most of the time it does not contain any speed information. I have to Copy&Paste the names and append the speeds by hand. As soon as I make one single error I have to begin from scratch.

So my question: Is there a way to make this easier?

I thougt ofsomthing like this: Making the CDDB query and writing the result i a text file, modify that file by hand and then continue ripping/encoding.

Do you have any ideas how to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have got it!

In the end I wrote my own scripts doing the nescessary steps. I went similar to [this description](http://www.gadgetweb.de/linux/cd-ripping-with-lame-cdda2wav-and-cddb-data.html). The main difference was that I used 2 scripts. One just reading out the CDs and collecting the data from the INF files in a large table. The other script encodes all WAV files and tags and renames them correctly. The table can be edited manually using any editor as it is plain text.

This has the benefit, that ripping and encoding can easyly be separated on different machines. In my case I use my old PC to rip (faster CD drive) and my new laptop to encode (8 CPUs to parallelize encodings).